# Can someone suggest how to - JS World Map/First Person Game Project

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js

I am planning a project for a game where the user can free roam a world in a number of different vehicles etc.

The world model needs to be relatively simple but I am trying to research the best way of doing it.

So far I had thought of an SVG world map that can be navigated in real-time (a kind of Google Street view arrangement) with the first person section being rendered using three.js.

While I have already created a database of select cities to navigate to I am unsure how to apply these to the SVG map/3D world/etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be rendering something that moves around a lot, [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas) is preferable to SVG. MSDN actually has a [good article on choosing between the two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg193983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Using a canvas, you can still draw geometric shapes and the like, and there are a number of decent frameworks out there for it. [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) is quite popular (though I have not used it).

Comment: I stumbled upon an SVG to canvas converter which essentially provided me with all the coordinates I needed so in going to run with that for now

Answer (score 1):

[Vizcities](http://rawkes.com/articles/announcing-vizicities) seems to be doing exactly what you want. They have chosen WebGL to visualise city data from geographical coordinates.

Comment: Looks interesting but not up and running yet

Comment: Why not join in and help?